# pass form data to database in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a search form which can search by id, name, country,etc. search field can have id or name or id and name or all fields like that way.as a final result I need a url to send to backend like 
 `http://localhost:8080/project/formData?id=1&name=myName`

How can I write a button in sencha ? can you give me a example ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the [`submit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit) method of your form.

There's an [example in the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/form/xml-form.html). Look at the js source to see how they implement the submit button.

Note that all the fields you want to send to the server should have a `name`.